# Getting error in database connection frequently on wordpress using docker-compose

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I am getting Error in Database connection frequently. It works fine for day or two but need to restart docker-compose manually every time it get this error.

can see anything significant when running docker-compose logs
What am I doing wrong ? Here..

DockerFile

```
FROM wordpress

COPY wp-config.php /var/www/html/

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

docker-compose
version: '3.1'

```
services:

  wordpress_db:
    container_name: abcwordpressdb
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - abcdb:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: abcphpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
        - wordpress_db:db
    ports:
        - "8181:80"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      PMA_HOST: wordpress_db

  wordpress:
    build: ./wordpress
    container_name: abc_wordpress
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content/
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  abcdb:
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue with either disk space or memory of your mariadb container. Have you checked memory usage and disk space at the moment this error occured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution here 
https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/361

Just make sure to run backup before running this

```
# Backup
docker exec CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=root DATABASE > backup.sql

# Restore
cat backup.sql | docker exec -i CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=root DATABASE
```

Then

1. `docker-compose down`
2. Deleted old volumes (if there is no significant data) `docker system prune --force --volumes`
3. Added `command: --disable-partition-engine-check` to mysql section in docker-compose.yml
4. Ran it with `docker-compose up -d` to set it up in background.

Answer (score 1):

Database containers at times take longer to come up.
So when your application container 'depends on' a database connection. It's nice to use the option

```
depends_on:
  - wordpress_db
```

This will make sure the database container comes up before the application